# Fastest way to fill numpy array with zeros and ones

Tags: python, numpy, random

I want to fill randomly a numpy array with arbitrary size with zeroes and ones. On each entry there should be a one with probability p.

```
    for x in range(l):
        rn = numpy.random.uniform(0, 1)
        if rn <= p:
            arr[x] = 1.0
        else:
            arr[x] = 0.0
```

Do you know a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use the [Binomial distribution](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.binomial.html#numpy.random.binomial).

```
arr = numpy.random.binomial(1, p, count)
```